# Wrong json format

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a service that returns me json data in the following format:
    `"[{\"Id\":3,\"Name\":\"name1\",\"Age\":30,\"Course\":\"course1\",\"SchoolName\":\"school1\",\"City\":\"city1\",\"Country\":\"country1\",\"BuildDate\":null}]"`

But I think this could be the source of my problems at the client because I think it shoul be more like:

`"[{"Id":3,"Name":"name1","Age":30,"Course":"course1","SchoolName":"school1","City":"city1","Country":"country1","BuildDate":null}]"`

I'm serializing this way:

```
string model = //mydata to serialize
string jsonStringToSend = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(model);
```

How can I fix this?

**Update**

After remove the double serialization as suggested, I'm getting now:

`[{Id:3, Name:name1, Age:30, Course:course1, SchoolName:school1, City:city1, Country:country1, BuildDate:null}]`

Comment: Fix the service that sends the JSON.

Comment: That format is fine, it's escaping all of the quotes for you, this is standard

Comment: That happens if you double-serialize. Do you give it back in asp.net with Responseformat.Json?

Comment: Why is your model a string and why serialize it then?

Comment: @MaxBurucker, You ar right, I was doing double-serialize (`return Json(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(model), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`). Now I get json string without quotes or backslash. But at think I need to get the json with quotes, like this: http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=javasript

Comment: @amp Can you edit in your post what you are getting back right now?

Comment: @MaxBurucker Question updated.

Comment: this doesnt look like a proper JSON respone anymore i just thought about a work arround with just replacing the \ on the client side with regex isnt really the perfect solution but would work i guess

Answer (score 0):

The `\"` is used to escape the `"` character. If it's literally being printed like this, you're probably escaping the `\` as well.